# How to calculate the points after rotate degrees and rotate to direction vector by using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

How to calculate the point A to H after rotate degrees and rotate to direction vector(-42,51,11) by using three.js ?

Thank you in advance and please excause my bad english. Best regards.

```
const tree = [
    [   0,   0,   0],  // A
    [   2, 151,   2],  // B
    [ -62, 283,  63],  // C
    [  62, 296, -58],  // D 
    [-104, 334,  74],  // E
    [ -58, 338,  45],  // F
    [  67, 403, -55],  // G
    [ 105, 365, -86],  // H
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: You need to define a rotation matrix, and than apply that matrix to each vertex. Look at the source code of Three.js for examples on how to do this. For example, check out the matrix definition here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Matrix4.js#L651 and the vertex rotation here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Vector3.js#L274 You may even be able to directly use Three.js to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Maarten VeermanThank you for your answer sincerely.Can you provided more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will apply a rotation to all the vectors in the tree of 90 degrees, around the axis defined as a vertex `[-42, 51, 11]`. So the rotation axis is defined as a line from `[0,0,0]` to `[-42, 51, 11]`, therefore point `A` does not change in rotation.

```js
const tree = [
    [   0,   0,   0],  // A
    [   2, 151,   2],  // B
    [ -62, 283,  63],  // C
    [  62, 296, -58],  // D 
    [-104, 334,  74],  // E
    [ -58, 338,  45],  // F
    [  67, 403, -55],  // G
    [ 105, 365, -86],  // H
  ] 

// Define the rotation axis:
let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-42, 51, 11)

// Normalize the axis:
axis.normalize()

// Define the matrix:
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()

// Define the rotation in radians:
let radians = 90 * Math.PI / 180

// Rotate the matrix:
matrix.makeRotationAxis(axis, radians)

// Now apply the rotation to all vectors in the tree
let newTree = []
for(const vector of tree) {
  // Define the vector3:
  let vec = new THREE.Vector3(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2])
  vec.applyMatrix4(matrix)
  newTree.push(vec.toArray()) // toArray is optional, you may want to keep the original Vector3 object
}

// newTree now holds the rotated vectors
console.log(newTree)
```

See https://codepen.io/mtveerman/pen/PoZZpvw for working version

Comment: @MaartenVeermanThank you for your answer so much.It is easy for me to understand.